# Formatting list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I'm fairly new to Tex and I don't know how to solve this simple problem. I have a section for my bibliography and I use subbibliography as header of my bibliographies. This works fine and looks the way I want. But now I added a list of figures and I want the header to look the same way as the headers of my other two bibliographies. How do I do that?

```
\section{Bibliography}
\printbibliography[type=inbook,title={Written sources},heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[type=article,title={Internet sources},heading=subbibliography]
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of figures}
\listoffigures
```

Comment: You can try to mimic the heading of your bibliography with `titletoc` or `tocloft`.

Comment: Could you help me with this? I'm not able to mimic the heading with titletoc.

Comment: Could you post a minimal compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`?